# Plotting mfp formula in geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, mfp

I have the following example code:

```
library(mfp)
library(ggplot2)

duration <- sample(c(3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14), 500, TRUE) 
data <- data.frame(duration = duration, 
                   score = -0.0125*duration^2 + 0.25*duration - 0.4 + rnorm(500, 0, 0.1))

mfp1 <- mfp(score ~ fp(duration), data)

ggplot(data, aes(x = duration, y = score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm",
              formula = mfp1$formula)
```

where I am generating some example data, fitting a fractional polynomial then plotting the scatter plot with the function on top. I am getting an error, as the `formula` parameter in `geom_smooth` needs to take a formala in the form `y ~ x`, whereas the formula from `mfp1` is `score ~ I((duration/10)^1) + I((duration/10)^2)`.

Is there a way to convert the formula from `mfp1` into a generic xy format for this use?

NB this is example data, the real application will be within a package, and therefore necessitates a general solution.

Comment: My mistake, change the top line to `duration = sample(c(3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14), 500, TRUE)
data <- data.frame(duration = duration,
                   score = -0.0125*duration^2 + 0.25*duration - 0.4 + rnorm(500, 0, 0.1))`, and yes it is `library(mfp)`

Answer (score 1):

Inside `geom_smooth`, you can use any `method` that produces an object which has a `predict` method, so instead of `method = "glm"` you can use `method = mfp` directly - at least in theory.

The problem is that `mfp` doesn't accept a `weights` argument, but `geom_smooth` always passes one to the `method`, even if the weights vector is empty or isn't used. Normally, this isn't a problem because many modelling functions have a "weights" argument, or "soak up" unused arguments by having a `...` parameter in the method definition. Unfortunately `mfp` has neither. This means we need to define a little wrapper function that can take arbitrary extra arguments and not use them.

Note that in `geom_smooth`, the `formula` argument also has to be given in terms of `x` and `y`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mfp)

ggplot(data, aes(x = duration, y = score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = function(formula, data, ...) mfp(formula, data), 
              formula = y ~ fp(x))
```

[image]

Note that you don't need the actual model to draw the plot, since `geom_smooth` re-runs the model when you plot.

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)
duration <- sample(c(3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14), 500, TRUE)
score    <- -0.0125 * duration^2 + 0.25 * duration - 0.4 + rnorm(500, 0, 0.1)
data     <- data.frame(score, duration)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>